# Bootstrap column at the center of parent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay, I've seen a lot of answers but I still could not get this correctly. 
I have this green column in which there are 2 smaller columns:
[image]
**I need to make the yellow column in the center.**
Like this:
[image]
I tried multiple methods, but none work. Of course margin-top works, but then the mobile screen is not ok. I know that there is a simple solution out there.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-success" style="margin-bottom: 50px; margin-top: 50px;">
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12"> 

            <!-- LEFT SIDE - Easy Cafe -->
            <div class="col-lg-7 bg-warning">
            <center class="jumbotextstyle">
                <div style="font-size: 100px;"> Easy Cafe <br> </div>
                <hr width="50%" style="border: 1px solid black; margin: 10px;">
                Makes ordering easier
            </center>
            </div>

            <!-- RIGHT SIDE - Picture-->
            <div class="col-lg-5 bg-danger">
            <center>
                <img src="images/s8.png" class="img-responsive" alt="mobilepicnotworking">
            </center> 
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.jumbotextstyle{
    font-size: 250%;
}
```

Comment: Okay fixed that. Thanks @j08691 and Abhishek Pandey

Answer (score 0):

Give your parent div (Green Div) a css property **Display: Flex** and **align-items: center**.

This will put both your div to horizontally and vertically to the center.

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8o29y7pd/3/)

HTML CODE :

```
<div id="container"><!-- flex container -->

<div class="box" id="bluebox"><!-- flex item -->
    <p>DIV #1</p>
</div>

<div class="box" id="redbox"><!-- flex item -->
    <p>DIV #2</p>
</div>
```

CSS CODE :

```
#container {
    display: flex; /* establish flex container */
    flex-direction: row; /* make main axis horizontal (default value) */
    justify-content: center; /* center items horizontally, in this case */
    align-items: center; /* center items vertically, in this case */
    height: 300px; /* for demo purposes */
    border: 1px solid black; /* for demo purposes */
    background-color: #eee; /* for demo purposes */
}

.box {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

#bluebox { background: aqua; }
#redbox { background: red; }
```

Comment: I added display: flex; align-items: center; to the green div, but it's still not vertically centered.

Comment: I edited the answer. Please visit the link.

Comment: Your parent div must have fix height in pixel or percentage.